# Register a C# COM component?

Tags: c++, com, unmanaged, regsvr32

I have developed a C# com component which I am using from managed c++. On my dev machine when everything works fine. However when I distribute the files, I received an error that the component has not been registered. When I try a regsvr32 on the dll it gives me an error (C# dlls cannot be registered). How do I properly register this COM dll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [regasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28VS.71%29.aspx) with `/codebase` (and it needs to be ComVisible [but as [Patrick McDonald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61989/patrick-mcdonald) correctly poinhts out, you've already got past that as it works locally])

Comment: It must already be ComVisible if it works on Dev machine, +1 for regasm

Answer (score 1):

Use RegAsm with siwtch `/codebase` if your assembly is not installed in the GAC (Global Assembly Cache).

[Details of further switches is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I find that you normally need to do:

```
regasm /codebase
```

Because COM needs to know the exact location of your assembly to be able to load it.

As others have suggested, you will need to set you C# project as COM visible (project settings, application, assembly information button).

Finer control of which classes are visible or not can be obtained using the [ComVisible(true)] / [ComVisible(false)] attribute before each class

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Assembly Registration Tool (Regasm.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(VS.71).aspx)